# how to compile/invoke peoplecode from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, peoplesoft

I know that we use AppDesigner to compile/build the people code. is there any way i can call/invoke the APPdesigner from jenkins to build the peoplcecode.
I am looking for continuous integration for peoplesoft/peoplecode

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Great question.  There is a java program called DecodePcode that extracts peoplecode that could be used as a template for this.

I'm not aware of a way to invoke app designer in a way that will validate the peoplecode in the editor, programmatically.

You could investigate a gui testing tool like sikuli, where you can script the opening of app designer and opening the peoplecode.

Please let me what you find, as I'm interesting in this as well.
Thanks,
-Alexei

Answer (score 0):

You can call App Designer from the command line to use the [App Designer Command Line Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E58500_01/pt854pbh1/eng/pt/tlcm/concept_UnderstandingPeopleSoftApplicationDesignerCommandLineParameters-07741f.html#topofpage) to compile the PeopleCode in either the entire database or a specific project.